# Access query: Delete duplicated records based on max value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table structure :

[image: Mail Contacts with Quality Score]

I would like to be able to delete from the table the duplicated mails, leaving for each mail account only the one with the highest quality score. At the moment I have come up with the following SQL code :

```
DELETE *
FROM Table
WHERE ( Table.[Email Adress] &  Table.[Quality Score] ) NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT  (Table.[Email Adress] & Max(Table.[Quality Score])
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY  Table.[Email Adress]
    );
```

However when I run it, it asks me for a parameter value and clearly doesn't work as I intended.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query to this:

```
DELETE FROM Table AS t
WHERE t.[Quality Score] <> (
    SELECT Max([Quality Score])
    FROM Table
    WHERE [Email Adress] = t.[Email Adress]
);
```

No need to `GROUP BY [Email Adress]` but you need a `WHERE` clause.
Or with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM Table AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Table
  WHERE [Email Adress] = t.[Email Adress] AND [Quality Score] > t.[Quality Score]
);
```

In case there are duplicate scores then you can keep the row with the highest score and the lowest id like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Table
  WHERE [Email Adress] = t.[Email Adress] 
    AND ([Quality Score] > t.[Quality Score] OR ([Quality Score] = t.[Quality Score] AND id < t.id))
);
```

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, yesterday I may have corrected it on the fly without noticing and it worked : in the last line of your code the second member of the OR is ([Quality Score]  = t.[Quality Score] AND id < t.id). Could you confirm is correct?

Comment: @mlm0b11011 yes it should be `=`. Thanks. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
delete from t
where t.quality_score < (select max(t2.quality_score)
                         from t as t2
                         where t2.email_address = t.email_address
                        );
```

Note:  If you have duplicate highest scores, this keeps all of them.  To address, you can use the `id` column:

```
delete from t
where t.id <> (select top 1 t2.id
               from t as t2
               where t2.email_address = t.email_address
               order by t2.quality_score desc, id
              );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff, the first one works fine. I've been testing the second one for a while and gives me a syntax error. I am sure it's me, but I've also created a new t testing table just to copy paste your code and test it out without touching it and avoiding any typing mistake on my part, but still get the message error. I will try another test later as soon as I have more time. Thank you again!

Comment: @mlm0b11011 . . . MS Access may be finicky about the parentheses around `1`.

Comment: Yes, that's what it was, it works perfectly fine now!